# Excel SQL Data Query Into Pivot Table Fails When Parameter Stored

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, odbc

I have a spreadsheet that has a pivot table with ODBC data query that passes two date parameters to the query to give a date range.

[query Parameter box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjNu0.png)

This works perfectly fine if I leave it so the user is prompted to provide a value or cell reference each time the data is refreshed, however if the user then chooses to store the parameter value as a cell reference using the "Use this value/reference for future refreshes" option the query throws up the following error.

[Query refresh error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvePE.png)

This only seems to affect a query directly into a pivot table, doing the same to an identical query into a tabular output works correctly.All queries have been created through the UI rather than VBA, has anyone come across this before as I'm completely stumped as to why?

Thanks in advance,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the reference cell gets 'lost'.

If you close and re-open spreadsheet, the parameters are not present.  Excel crashes if you attempt to refresh in this condition.

The parameters are saved within the workbook (check by changing extension to .zip, look in the xl folder for connections.xml) , they are just not 'loaded' when the spreadsheet is opened.

This is a 5 year old issue.  MicroSoft has not been helpful with a resolution.  Perhaps someone can figure out how to inject the parameters?